# How to use hasManyThrough relation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have problem with hasManyThrough relation in my Laravel project.

I want to get all people connected with selected Event.

My tables looks like:

```
Events:
- id
- name
- ...

Tickets:
- id
- event_id
- person_id
- ...

People
- id
- first_name
- ...
```

And in my Event model:

```
public function people()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Person::class, Ticket::class);
}
```

So, how to get all people? eg.

```
Event::first()->people
```

Comment: I think your person needs a ticket_id and you should only need the event_id in tickets. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: `HasManyThrough` is the wrong relationship here. Use `BelongsToMany` instead: https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this
in the people model

```
public function events(){
return $this->hasMany('App\Events');
}
```

and in the event table

```
public function people(){
return $this->belongsTo('App\people');
}
```

to get all the people you can do this $people = people::all(); and the events $people->events->name